# How to retrieve last record of one to many relationship table in laravel

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have two tables named `Member` and `Deposit` in a **one to many** relationship.

One `member` has **multiple saving amounts** in `deposit` table. The `deposit` table every single amount of each `member` will calculate and store in 'total_amount' column in 'Deposit' table.

I have to search `Member` by `branch_id` and `post-id` and display it's last 'total_amount' of 'Deposit' table

How can I do this?

My `Member` Table:

```
id
branch_id
post_id
name
phone
address
```

My Deposit Table:

```
id
member_id
deposit_date
amount
total_amount
```

My controller:

```
$members = Member::where('branch_id',$request->branch_id)->where('post_id',$request->post_id)->get();
```

Blade template:

```
@foreach($members as member)
  <td>{{$member->name}}</td>
  <td>{{$member->address}}</td>
  <td>{{$member->deposit->total_amount}}</td> // i want to display here last deposit table total_amount of every member
 @endforeach
```

When I do this in Laravel blade file, all relational record of deposit table are displaying in JSON format.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withCount()` and modify it:

```php
$members = Member::withCount(['deposits as total_amount' => function($query) {
        $query->select('total_amount')->latest('deposit_date')->limit(1);
    }])
    ->where('branch_id', $request->branch_id)
    ->where('post_id', $request->post_id)
    ->get();

{{ $member->total_amount }}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jonas Staudenmeir and please suggest me another problem . If any member fail to deposit one ,two or more month how can i show and count his failure quantity , and how to show his next deposit date  based on deposit_date column of Deposit table.My Member table another column are account_open_date and duration_month.

Comment: `@Jonas Staudenmeir ` If i want to show all calumn of `Deposit ` table then what i have to do?